# How to randomly select a proportion of key-value pairs from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've already had a dictionary where `len(sample)=5`

```
sample={'a':[1,2],'b':[5,2],'c':[88,3],'d':[63,55],'e':[77,9]}
```

I want to make a new dictionary which only contains three pairs from `sample`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import choice

test = {}
while len(test) < 3:
    t = choice(sample.keys())
    if t not in test.keys():
        test[t] = sample[t]

print(test)
```